# QPainter updating data

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have a problem with updating drawing. I have 2 files: mainwindow.cpp and drawwidget.cpp. In mainwindow I load a file with x,y point parameters. When I click a button, I choose few of them and I pass it to drawwidget to draw this points.

To see how it will works, temporarily I draw an ellipse and I multiply "p" times size. When I click a button, "p" changes value (I printed it in QMessageBox, and its different value), but ellipse is still same size. What I do wrong?

```
DrawWidget::DrawWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    p=30;
}
void DrawWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter painter(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &painter, this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    paint(painter);
}
void DrawWidget::paint(QPainter &painter)
{
    painter.drawEllipse( QRect( 1*p-5, 5*p-5, 10, 10 ) );
}
void DrawWidget::handleData(sPunkt *&Tab_pkt)
{
    p=Array[0].x;
    update();
}
```

Comment: Well the last 2 parameters of [`QRect::QRect(int, int, int, int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#QRect-3) are width and height, which are constants in your code (`10`). So the size shouldn't change. You are only changing the position.

Comment: Yes, my fault, but I wrote it to see if anything is changing and nothing is happening when I change p value

Comment: Ok, then check the value of `p` in the `paint` method. Print a `QDebug` message or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) your widget in order to trigger [`QPaintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html#details) and following call to [`paintEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

> A paint event is a request to repaint all or part of a widget. It can
>   happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> - repaint() or update() was invoked,
> - the widget was obscured and has now been uncovered, or
> - many other reasons.

See docs: [`QWidget::paintEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent)

Comment: I updated it here: `void DrawWidget::handleData(sPunkt *&Tab_pkt)
{
    p=Array[0].x;
    update();
}`, but it doesnt work.